# Required Help for Writing SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have two tables below.

**Item Table**

This Item Table contains ItemId and Total Quantity

```
ItemID   TotalItems     

 1        10

 2        10

 3        10

 4        10
```

**OrderHistory**

Table This Order history table contains ItemId and OrderId

```
orderId    ItemID

 11          1

 12          1

 13          2

 14          2

 15          3
```

I want to get result which contains ItemID and total Items Used for example for Item Id 1 , there are two order in orderhistory so I want result like below

Remaining Items( Formula : Total Items from ItemTable - count of Same ItemId from Orderhistory table)

Final output :

**ItemId Remaining Items**

```
1    8

2    8

3    9

4    10
```

so How to write SQL Query for that.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT i.ItemID, i.TotalItems - COUNT(h.ItemID) AS RemainingItems
FROM ItemTable i
    LEFT JOIN OrderHistory h
        ON i.ItemId = h.ItemId
GROUP BY i.ItemId, i.TotalItems
```

Comment: While I was messing about in SQL fiddle you already answered the question :) so for the sake of not wasting my time completely I'll add sql fiddle link here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22e95/1